# This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times after submit

Tags: php

```
$setStr = "";
    foreach($data as $key => $v)
    {
        if($key != "id")
        {
            $setStr .= "`$key` = :$key,";
        }
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE ". $table ." SET ". $setStr ." WHERE ID = :id";

    $stmt = $this->db()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
```

I have the following code:

```
        if(!$valid)
        {
            $msg = new ErrorView(create_element('p', ['content' => $msg], true, ['style' => ["text-align: center;"]]));
            $msg->generateHTML();
            header("Location: ". Route::get('edit')->generate(['id' => $this->id]));
        }
        else
        {
            $data = [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'password' => sha1($_POST['password']) . sha1(time())
            ];
            $user->update_user($data);
            header("Location: ". Route::get('account')->generate(['id' => $this->id]));
        }
```

and in form action="#" and I'm keep getting the message This page isn’t workinglocalhost redirected you too many times.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: after each header Location, add "die();"

Comment: @svgta I made mistake in query, thats why I had that error